# Hilbert space version of the notion of conditionally weakly-mixing functions.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\|#1\|}$ $\newcommand{\ab}[1]{\langle #1\rangle}$ $\newcommand{\mr}{\mathscr}$ $\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}$ $\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E}$ $\newcommand{\C}{\mathbf C}$

## Background/Definitions

Let $(X, \mc X, \mu, T)$ be an invertible measure preserving system.
A function $f\in L^2$ is said to be **weakly-mixing** if
$$
\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} |\ab{f, T^n f}|^2 = 0
$$

This definition can be given for a more abstract setting.
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space equipped with a unitary operator $U:H\to H$.
A point $x\in H$ is said to be **weakly-mixing** if
$$
\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} |\ab{x, T^nx}|^2 = 0
$$

Now suppose $\mc D$ and $\mc A$ are $T$-invariant sub-$\sigma$-algebras of $\mc X$ with $\mc A\subseteq \mc D$.
Then we have a factor map $(X, \mc D, \mu, T)\to (X, \mc A, \mu, T)$ mapping $x$ to $x$.
Thus $(X, \mc D)$ is an extension of $(X, \mc A)$.
We define a **conditional inner product** on $L^2(\mc D)$ as
$$
\ab{f, g}_{(\mc D|\mc A)} = \E[f\bar g| \mc A]
$$
for all $f, g\in L^2(\mc D)$.
Note that the "inner product" is valued in $L^1(\mc A)$ and not in $\C$.
Let $L^2(\mc D|\mc A)$ be the subspace of $L^2(\mc D)$ consisting of all $f\in L^2(\mc D)$ such that
$$
\norm{f}_{(\mc D|\mc A)} := \sqrt{\E[|f|^2|\mc A]}
$$
is in $L^\infty(\mc A)$.

**Definition.**
A function $f\in L^2(\mc D| \mc A)$ is said to be **conditionally weakly-mixing** if for each $g\in L^2(\mc D|\mc A)$ we have
$$
\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \|\ab{T^nf, g}_{(\mc D|\mc A)}\|_{L^2(\mc A)}^2 = 0
$$

This is a natural conditional version of the non-conditional definition given above.

## Question

> **Question.** Is there a Hilbert space version of definition of conditionally weakly-mixing.

The first thing that comes to mind is to consider a Hilbert space $K$ equipped with a unitary operator $U$, and let $H$ be a $U$-invariant closed linear subspace of $K$.
Thus $K$ mimics $L^2(\mc D)$ and $H$ mimics $L^2(\mc A)$.

Since the adjoint of the inclusion $L^2(\mc A)\to L^2(\mc D)$ is the conditional expectation map $\E[\cdot|\mc A]:L^2(\mc D)\to L^2(\mc A)$, we may define the conditional inner product of $x$ and $y$ in $K$ as $\ab{x, y}_{(K|H)} = \ab{i^*x, i^*y}_H$, where $i:H\to K$ is the inclusion map and $i^*$ is the adjoint of $i$.
However, $\ab{x, y}_{(K|H)}$ is a complex number, unlike in the case of the conditional inner product.
So perhaps we need more structure on the Hilbert space to come up with a proper definition.